# How do I make an array of Priority Queues? Further how to assign comparator function to each PQ in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, priority-queue

I somehow came across a requirement to create an Array of PriorityQueues.
A workaround could be to create a HashMap, but I prefered array.

I declared an Array of Priority Queues as follows.

`PriorityQueue<long[]>[] arr = new PriorityQueue[10];`

I wanted each Priority Queue in `arr` to have a same comparator function that sorts elements in `PriorityQueue<long[]>`, in order of second element inside `long[]`.

I tried to fill the array `arr` using.

```
Arrays.fill(arr, new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<>(){
            public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
                return b[1] - a[1];
            }
        }));
```

But this gives me an error, can anyone help what is wrong with this approach?

The Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<long[]>[] arr = new PriorityQueue[10];
        Arrays.fill(arr, new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<>(){
            public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
                return b[1] - a[1];
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
Main.java:12: error: <anonymous Main$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Object,Object) in Comparator
        Arrays.fill(arr, new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<>(){
                                                               ^
Main.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
                       ^
  (due to <>, every non-private method declared in this anonymous class must override or implement a method from a supertype)
```

Also is there a better way to assign object to each element of array during declaration?

Comment: Is one of the error messages  a compiler error message "generic array creation" ?  Those who update Java chose to implement generics in a way that makes them incompatible with arrays. You migth try something like `List<PriorityQueue<long[]>> arr   = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I added the error and full code. Can you please explain what exactly causes this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an object with a comparator, you can use this approach:

```java
PriorityQueue<Long[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Long[]>() {
    public int compare(Long[] a, Long[] b) {
        return a[1].compareTo(b[1]);
    }
});
```

But note I have used `Long` not `long` and this allows me to also use `compareTo` instead of subtraction - to ensure you do not encounter unexpected out-of-bounds results for `Compare`'s `int` return value.

---

The above uses the anonymous inner class approach you were looking to use in your question, but note also the explicit type `Comparator<Long[]>`.

As an optional extra step, this can be simplified by replacing the inner class with a lambda expression:

```java
PriorityQueue<Long[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((Long[] a, Long[] b) -> a[1].compareTo(b[1]));
```

Therefore you can use either of the above approaches in your `Arrays.fill`.

Here is the lambda approach:

```java
PriorityQueue<long[]>[] arr = new PriorityQueue[10];
Arrays.fill(arr, new PriorityQueue<>((Long[] a, Long[] b) -> a[1].compareTo(b[1])));
```

---

Just to note - that comparator may only be an artificial example for this question, but it is a bit unusual. And I was wondering if you actually meant to compare `a[0]` with `b[0]` instead.

And, obviously, all the queues are empty at this point.

---

**Update**

I completely agree with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966386/how-do-i-make-an-array-of-priority-queues-further-how-to-assign-comparator-func#comment133986258_75966386) from @OldDogProgrammer. Mixing generics and arrays in this way is not recommended. "*Prefer lists to arrays*" - Josh Bloch, *Effective Java*.

---

**Update 2**

You asked if I could:

> provide some reference or some reading material

That is why I mentioned Josh Bloch and *Effective Java*. You can do an online search for "prefer lists to arrays josh bloch" to see various articles discussing this topic, in depth.

You asked:

> what causes the error here?

You have not provided a specific type for `new Comparator<>()`.

That is why I mentioned "*note also the explicit type `Comparator<Long[]>`*" in my answer (see above).

The objects you want the comparator to compare are `Long[]` arrays - but you provided `int[]` in your implementation:

```
compare(int[] a, int[] b)
```

You have not provided any type at all in your `new Comparator<>()` constructor - therefore it defaults to `compare(Object,Object)` - which you can see in the error message.

So, there is also a mismatch between the constructor and the implementation you have provided - as well as a mismatch between the constructor and what you *should* have provided in the implementation.

This is actually another Josh Bloch topic:

> Prefer generic types.

There are excellent online articles about this topic, also. I expect there are also some excellent Stack Overflow answers about this, and "*Prefer lists to arrays*".

You can also search for terms *covariant* and *invariant* in the context of Java generics and arrays as another research topic.

Comment: Can you please provide some reference or some reading material on why is "Mixing generics and arrays" is not recommended? Also I updated the question, can you please explain what causes the error here? I try to fill array with a new PriorityQueue Object in which I passed a comparator object for each PQ object in array. What error am I making?

Comment: OK - I have added some notes to my answer - hope they help. These are large bu(and important) topics, so I have tried to provide some pointers for more exploration.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it clears a lot of things for me.